# How to search for predefined strings and returned the whole line if a match is found

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The snippet work partially as it can produce some results. I need help to make it fully works. I am searching for strings in a url and if a partial match is found, the whole line will be returned.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

addrlist = ['0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371',
           '0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4',
           '0x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053']

queries = ["Website", "Telegram", "https://www.", "Twitter", "https://t.me"]
url = "https://bscscan.com/address/"


for i in addrlist:
      url = str(url) + str(i)

      r = requests.get(url)
      soup = bs(r.text,'lxml')

      pre = soup.select_one('pre.js-sourcecopyarea.editor')
      ss = (list(pre.stripped_strings)[0]).split('*')
      for s in ss:
             for query in queries:
                  if query in s:
                      print(s)
```

Current Output:

```
Website: https://binemon.io
Telegram: https://t.me/binemonchat
Twitter: https://twitter.com/binemonnft

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stripped_strings'
```

Wanted Output:

```
Website: https://binemon.io
Telegram: https://t.me/binemonchat
Twitter: https://twitter.com/binemonnft

// Telegram : https://t.me/stackdogebsc
// Website : https://www.stack-doge.com

*Website: www.shibuttinu.com
*Telegram: https://t.me/Shibuttinu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `url` variable. You concatenate each `addrlist` to the previous url:

```
# 1st iteration:
https://bscscan.com/address/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371

# 2nd iteration:
https://bscscan.com/address/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e607303710xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4

# 3rd iteration:
https://bscscan.com/address/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e607303710xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e40x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053
```

Change your code like this:

```
# url = "https://bscscan.com/address/"
baseurl = "https://bscscan.com/address/"

# url = str(url) + str(i)
url = str(baseurl) + str(i)
```

**Update**

Use regex to extract information.

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

addrlist = ['0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371',
            '0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4',
            '0x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053']

baseurl = "https://bscscan.com/address/"
pattern = r'(Website|Telegram|Twitter)\s*:\s*([^\s]+)'

for i in addrlist:
      url = str(baseurl) + str(i)

      r = requests.get(url)
      soup = bs(r.text,'lxml')

      pre = soup.select_one('pre.js-sourcecopyarea.editor')

      print(url)
      for match in re.findall(pattern, str(pre)):
          print(f"{match[0]}: {match[1]}")
      print()
```

Output:

```
https://bscscan.com/address/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371
Website: https://binemon.io
Telegram: https://t.me/binemonchat
Twitter: https://twitter.com/binemonnft

https://bscscan.com/address/0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4
Telegram: https://t.me/stackdogebsc
Website: https://www.stack-doge.com

https://bscscan.com/address/0x88c20beda907dbc60c56b71b102a133c1b29b053
Website: www.shibuttinu.com
Telegram: https://t.me/Shibuttinu
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the fix as you suggested. My problem still remains on how to just return the matching line.